# How To Rotate an UIImageView based on a point in Touches Moved Method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

**Dear All,**

I want to rotate a UIImageView relative to a point in touchesMoved method.

I tried 2 -3 methods but I am not getting the exact result what I expected to be.

First method I used

```
CGAffineTransform transforms = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

imgView.transform = transforms;
```

This is written in touchesMoved. So I expect a rotation for the image view in each touchesMoved.
But the rotation is occuring only once .

Second method I used was

```
CGAffineTransform transforms = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgView.transform, M_PI/2);

imgView.transform = transforms;
```

Now the result what I get is the image in Image view is continusely rotating in each move. But imageview is not rotating. What i need is to rotate the imageview not the image.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks & Best Regards,
Rupesh R Menon**

Comment: Yes. It's also not giving the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to achieve single finger rotation on the image. If it is so you can use following functions from one of my live working project. You can use this for single image as well as multiple images. You need to modify at some extend for multiple images. Best way is extend UIImageView class and create your own class.

From touches moved call this function

> - [self transformImagewithTouches:touch];

Declare 1 property and synthesize as follows. (Also please declare other variables if required in below code.

> - @property (nonatomic) CGFloat fltRotatedAngle;

```
-(void)transformImagewithTouches:(UITouch *)touchLocation
{
    //NSLog(@"Before %f",self.fltRotatedAngle);
    CGPoint touchLocationpoint = [touchLocation locationInView:[self superview]]; 
    CGPoint PrevioustouchLocationpoint = [touchLocation previousLocationInView:[self superview]];
    CGPoint origin;
    origin.x=self.center.x;
    origin.y=self.center.y;
    CGPoint previousDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:PrevioustouchLocationpoint];
    CGAffineTransform newTransform =CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 1, 1); 
    CGFloat previousRotation = atan2(previousDifference.y, previousDifference.x); 
    CGPoint currentDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:touchLocationpoint]; 
    CGFloat currentRotation = atan2(currentDifference.y, currentDifference.x);
    CGFloat newAngle = currentRotation- previousRotation; 

    //Calculate Angle to Store
    fltTmpAngle = fltTmpAngle+newAngle;
    self.fltRotatedAngle = (fltTmpAngle*180)/M_PI;  

    newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, newAngle);
    [self animateImageView:self toPosition:newTransform];   
}

-(void)animateImageView:(UIImageView *)theView toPosition:(CGAffineTransform) newTransform
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0750];   
    self.transform = newTransform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(CGPoint)vectorFromPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint
{
    CGFloat x = secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y; 
    CGPoint result = CGPointMake(x, y); 
    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps. If you stuck up please let me know I ll definitely help you.

Comment: Thank you Jennnis , It was really helpful. I was able to use some part from your code.

Comment: @Jennis,I want Both rotation as well as translation if i want to rotate and then drag my image to some other part of screen , how can i do it?

Comment: You will have to define action first i.e. what to do rotation or translation. and based on selected action act accordingly. you can get translation code easily from tutorials. and rotation as I have given.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the interest shown by you in helping me.

When I used the following code I was able to rotate the image view in my desired angle.

imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pCalculator.tangentToCornerAngle, 0, 0, 1);

where **imgView** is an UIImageView.

```
  pCalculator.tangentToCornerAngle  is the desired angle in which rotation has to be made.

Function is CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, <CGFloat y, CGFloat z);
```

Thankyou All,
Rupesh R Menon

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have rotated it by M_PI/2 and when you rotate it again it rotates it from the initial position. Use this one

```
CGAffineTransform transforms = CGAffineTransformConcat(imgView.transform,CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2));
imgView.transform = transforms;
```

Comment: Dear Inder,    I had tried what you suggested. But it's giving me the same result with that I used with second method. ie; image is rotating not image view. I need the image view to rotate.     Any how Thanks for the interest shown.

Comment: How would you say that imageView is not being rotated, your are rotating the imageView no the image that why the content is rotated...

Comment: My dear friend you must be having a square imageView so rotating it 90 degree makes it feel like same. either change its height or width (a rectangle not a square) then you can see the difference or you can rotate it 45 degree for testing purpose only. `M_PI/4`

Comment: No dear. My image view is a not of square size. Its purely rectangle.

Comment: but have tested it in a test project and it's working fine... just change the background color to red and put a smaller image inside it and make it contentMode to center